AWS ALB Rules Routing issue
I have two rules set up in my ALB:
One for routing to Travel APIs.
Another is for routing to App APIs, which includes endpoints like auth and user.
I want to redirect traffic based on the URL path. The rule for travel APIs is set as "/api/v1/travel/*", while the rule for App APIs is set to the default.
Now, when I call a travel API, like "/api/v1/travel/list", the ALB correctly sends the request to the travel target group. However, the problem arises when I call an app API, such as "/api/v1/auth/current". The first request gets served by the travel target group, and the second API gets served by the App target group.
I wonder why the ALB sends traffic to the Travel Target group when the URL "/api/v1/auth/current" doesn't match the travel rule. Is my rule path pattern correct?
Reference Image


Answering my question, the issue was not with the rules; the rules were working perfectly fine. The problem was that I ran two EC2s inside my default target group: one EC2 was serving Travel APIs and the other was serving APP APIs. By removing the TravelEC2 from the default target group, my issue was hence resolved.
